# Prestashop 1.7 custom popup on product page

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to create a custom pop-up in Prestashop 1.7 as there in this example - https://www.samsung.com/uk/smartphones/galaxy-a9/buy/

The following is the screenshot of the same example and what it looks like.

[image]

And on select of any of the options, the following pop-up

[image]

Is there any module to achieve this? If not, can anyone redirect me to a module on the same line. I do understand I need to use custom hooks here. But I'm not able to get a clear idea on how do I build using custom hook. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out how to do this. This has to be done by building a custom module. [Click here](http://validator.prestashop.com) to create a skeleton for your custom module. The folder structure would look something as shown below.

[image]

To learn more on how to build a custom module follow the link >>https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/introduction/